# Pygame sprite transformation with interpolation

Tags: python, animation, pygame, sprite, interpolation

Im currently working on a Python/Pygame module to wrap some basic sprite animation. Animation in the sense that the image itself is static but I apply **rotation** and **scale** with start and end values with a **sine wave interpolation**. That is, sprite transformation like the ones that could be made in Flash. I hope you understand, otherwise feel free to ask and I try to clarify.

I cant find a module that does this already. Does anyone know of one? Would save me some work. :)

**Edit:** Oh, and if this *transformation with interpolation* thingie has a proper name I would love to hear it. Would probably make my search results better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform images by [pygame.transform](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html), but interpolation is not included in pygame.

[Rabbyt](http://matthewmarshall.org/projects/rabbyt/) provides animation including interpolation, even though I haven't used it.

Comment: Thank you, the lib in the kind of Rabbyt was exactly what I was looking for. Probably easier to add the missing parts there than start from scratch.